# Scraping sound from front right wheel area

Tags: troubleshooting, seat-leon

Was driving earlier when noticed what sounds like scraping from drivers side front wheel. Doesn't make a sound while driving at normal speed. Only while driving slow or slowing down I've had in up on the jack and not making a sound unless I spin wheel one direction then quickly change direction but even then only a small knock then nothing. Have no idea what's causing the sound but sounds like something is scraping alone the ground (there isn't) 
It's a seat Leon 58 plate.

Answer (score 2):

You may not hear it at normal speed because perhaps the sound changes its pitch to some higher frequency, but that sound can be "mainly" two things:

a) brake pads wasted to their steel supports
b) bearings going out of lub

Check as this:

a) Jack the car, try to move the wheel first pulling in/out horizontally (one hand at 10:00 other hand at 3:00, and pull in/out one hand first then the other). If you feel it "loose", hear noises, clicks, etc you may have tie rods problems...great to find but that's not your issue :) Now do the same but vertically (one 12:00, the other 6:00, pull in/out...loose, noise, clicks means bearing problems)...that's what you need to address.

b) Jack the car, rotate the wheel to driving direction and with the help of someone "slightly" very slightly press brake pedal. The idea is not to stop the wheel but let the pads rub the disk then rear the noise. If something resembles what you heard, then the pads are done.

c) Jack the car, remove the wheel, visually inspect the brake pads. If needed, put the wheel fasteners to secure the brake disk and rotate it. With the help of a screwdriver pinch the pads. Also check if the dust cover inwards the brake system touches the disk, maybe it is bent or loose.

e) Silly but also makes those sounds: put the car on ground, check if there is any plastic cover, rubber, hose, etc rubbing the wheel!

Bearing problems are commonly a grinding non-intermittent sound. By scrapping sound I infer it is an intermittent sound, so maybe not the bearing...but good to check as in a) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check for an object between the breaking disc and the well behind it

There are instances of rocks getting stuck behind them and you might hear them at certain lower speeds. At higher speeds the frequency of the sound changes and other road and wind noises overlay the sound of the friction.

Jack the car, get the wheel off, then look between the disc and the well. See if there is an object between the two, usually a small rock. If so, use *e.g.* a screwdriver to remove the rock, make sure the disc and the well are still aligned properly and then put the wheel back on.

This is of course but an option. The suggestions by @AramAlvarez are just as valid.